# Ordenamiento de un Dictionary<int, ObjetoBinario>

Tags: c#

Tengo un `Dictionary<int, ObjetoBinario>`, donde el value tiene un Objeto (ObjetoBinario) con el atributo `posX` de tipo int.

Entonces ocupo que dicho diccionario sea ordenado segun este atributo, en forma ascendente.

Actualmente estoy utilizando lo siguiente:

```
Func<KeyValuePair<int, ObjetoBinario>, int> predicated = delegate (KeyValuePair<int, ObjetoBinario> item) {
    return item.Value.GetPosX();
};

IOrderedEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, ObjetoBinario>> ordered = objetos_binarios.OrderBy(predicated);

objetos_binarios = ordered;
```

Como se observa **`objetos_binarios`** es el Dictionary que ocupo ordenar mediante `GetPosX`.

Es correcto hasta el punto de ordenarlos en `ordered`, pero por funcionamiento de mi sistema; ocupo que el ordenamiento se guarde `objetos_binarios`.

El problema esta en la ultima linea, no me permite asignar `ordered` a `objetos_binarios`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al objeto `ordered` solo le debes hacer un `ToDictionary` especificando su llave y valor.

```
Func<KeyValuePair<int, ObjetoBinario>, int> predicated = delegate(KeyValuePair<int, ObjetoBinario> item)
{
    return item.Value.GetPosX();
};

IOrderedEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, ObjetoBinario>> ordered = objetos_binarios.OrderBy(predicated);

objetos_binarios = ordered.ToDictionary(c => c.Key, c => c.Value);
```

Otra forma seria obviar el `ordered`:

```
Func<KeyValuePair<int, ObjetoBinario>, int> predicated = delegate(KeyValuePair<int, ObjetoBinario> item)
{
    return item.Value.GetPosX();
};

objetos_binarios = objetos_binarios.OrderBy(predicated).ToDictionary(c => c.Key, c => c.Value);
```

Ó todo en una sola linea:

```
objetos_binarios = objetos_binarios.OrderBy(c => c.Value.GetPosX()).ToDictionary(c => c.Key, c => c.Value);
```